# limit an extension to a firefox container?

Tags: firefox-extensions

Is there a way to install a firefox extension within a single container?  I'd like to try some of the shopping extensions (Honey, SlickDeals), but they as for "all data on all sites" and that feels ooky.

Ideally, I'd like to set up the the "shopping" container and only have those extensions within that container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just went through the same thing (though this is 12 months late, so I may be too late)!

You can't do this with Firefox containers, what you want to use instead are Firefox Profiles:  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data

Here you can use a profile for shopping, with a specific set of extensions.  The UX is not as good!  But it does help restrict the tracking of these apps to just the shopping sites you want them to know about anyway.